# Finding stabilizer and left cosets of stabilizers in symmetric group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

[image]

This one is confusing me in a couple ways. When they talk about G is G implied to be $S_3$ or some arbitrary group. Also I'm just confused what the question is asking for in general. I know what a stabilizer is and does, but what is the family of left cosets of the stabilizer? And how would I draw a bijection?

Comment: Yes $G=S_3$. The stabilizer of $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, so we can speak of its cosets, and we can write out the cosets. Then we can write the left cosets and the conjugates of $H$ side-by-side in order to verify explicitly they are in one-to-one correspondence.

Comment: What would those look like could you give me an example?

Comment: Do the first thing first. Find the orbit of $H$ under conjugation. In other words, what are the conjugates of $H$? And, what is the stabilizer of $H$? Lastly, do you know what a coset is? If you know what a coset is, there's nothing stopping you from doing this problem.